# Tkinter <<ListboxSelect>> not calling bound function

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to bind an event to the <> event using Tkinter. I appear to be doing something wrong however, as SelectionChangeText function never gets called. The ClickTest event does get called without any issues.

I am using python 3.5

```
from tkinter import *

if __name__ == "__main__":
    def SelectionChangeTest(event):
        print("Selection Change Test")

    def ClickTest(event):
        print("Click Test")

    root = Tk()

    newWidget = Listbox(root)
    newWidget.insert(END, "Object 1")
    newWidget.insert(END, "Object 2")
    newWidget.bind("<<ListBoxSelect>>",SelectionChangeTest)
    newWidget.bind("<Button-1>",ClickTest)
    newWidget.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

Thank you much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event name is `"<<ListboxSelect>>"` not `"<<ListBoxSelect>>"`.

Comment: I'm really sad how long I spent trying to figure that out. Thanks so much!